# PHP : Remove duplicate values from associative array and return an associative array containing the duplicate values

Tags: php, associative-array

I have associative array like below

```
$arr = [1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>2]
```

I would like to remove the duplicate values from the initial array and return those duplicates as a new array. So I would end up with something like;

```
$arr = [1=>0, 4=>2]

$new_arr = [2=>1, 3=>1]
```

Does PHP provide such a function or if not how would I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want save indexes?

Comment: Yes, its important that I save indexes

Comment: Dharma's answer solved the problem that I asked. However, having moved on a little I find out that I now need the result like this                '$arr = [1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>2, 6=>3]'

Comment: I think it's better to create a new qiestion with good explanation what numbers in array does mean

Comment: @dharma-parmar Dharma's answer solved the problem that I asked. However, having moved on a little I find out that I now need the result like this                                                                                                        '$arr = [1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>2, 6=>3]' becomes                                                                                                    '$arr = [1=>0, 4=>2, 6=>3]'                                 '$new_arr = [[2=>1, 3=>1], [4=>2, 5=>2]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Use `array_filter()` to get all duplicate values from array

Use `array_diff()` to get all unique values from array

```
$array = array(1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>2);
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$duplicates = array_filter($array, function ($value) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$value] > 1;
});
print '<pre>';print_r($duplicates);

$result=array_diff($array,$duplicates);
print '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
)

Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [4] => 2
)
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can get unique values from an array using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and then compare the resulting array with [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

This will keep the indexes for both arrays, here's an example:

```
$arr = array(1=> 2, 2=>2, 3=>3);
print_r($arr);
$arr1 = array_unique($arr);
print_r($arr1);
$arr2 = array_diff_assoc($arr,$arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
Array
(
    [2] => 2
)
```